# Decrypting Webpush payload on a Ruby server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-push

I'm looking for a way to decrypt Webpush messages that get posted to a Ruby server. Typically webpushes go to a user agent such as a web browser and the browser decrypts them. In this particular case, I have webpushes configured to go to a Ruby server where I'd like to further process them. I've looked at gems such as https://github.com/zaru/webpush but it appears this only handles the encryption side of things.

What's the best way to decrypt a webpush message using a ruby server?

Comment: This is some really interesting stuff you are trying to do :P

Comment: What's the benefit of using this, vs say, a message queue?

Comment: does ruby server directly receive a message from another server? or client send a encrypted message?

Comment: Have you tried the [ECE](https://github.com/randomlogin/ece) gem, which is used by [webpush/encryption_spec.rb](https://github.com/zaru/webpush/blob/master/spec/webpush/encryption_spec.rb) to verify encrypted data?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following C library to decrypt those messages which would typically be decrypted by a web browser, but I believe there is more to this.

https://github.com/web-push-libs/ecec#web-push

Comment: I need to figure out how to do this in Ruby, the above code is in C and I have no way to verify what it's doing or how it works.

Comment: You can call the library via system calls from inside ruby

Answer (score 0):

I haven't learned anything about WebPush before, but if browsers "auto-decrypt" as you say, then here's a crazy idea that'd get you up-and-running:

Use your server as a "trusted Man-in-the-Middle" by using [browser automation](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/rb) to run Chrome on the server.

By controlling the browser, you can have it receive the WebPush as "normal", and then you can also write & inject additional JavaScript on the webpage to POST it decrypted to the local server.